# This is regarding Exact Target API terminology. I am currently trying to test TriggeredSend in php. I am currently learning and testing samples

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, php, fuel-sdk

Can anybody advise what is email ID (email->ID) here in below code ? I didn't understand what this is and why we require this ? Where do we find this value ? can we find these in marketing cloud admin.

```
$email = new ExactTarget_Email();
$email->ID = "12345";$emailSendDef->Email = $email;

Along with that where we can find the list id in the below code ?

$sendDefList = new ExactTarget_SendDefinitionList();
$list = new ExactTarget_List();$list->ID = "12345";

And CustomerKey,Name

$emailSendDef = new ExactTarget_EmailSendDefinition();
$emailSendDef->CustomerKey = "12345";
$emailSendDef->Name = "test";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listID is can be found on in the properties of the publication list used for the send. This usually defaults to the All Subscribers List. To access this ,

- Navigate to Email Studio > Subscribers > All Susbcribers List
- Click on Properties
- The List Id should be visible here

[image]

The customer key for the send definition can be can also be retrieved in a similar manner.

- Navivgate to Email Studio > Interactions > Triggered Emails
- Your Customer Key is your External Key.

You can also access these via API.
[image]

Comment: thank u kid, i need a small clarification regarding the list id,whether we have to use Publication List  Id or All Susbcribers List Id

Comment: If you want to send off a particular publication list, then it would be the publication list id, otherwise default to the all subscribers list

Comment: thank u kid.i need to send only to one subscriber then can i go with publication list.

Comment: You can use the AllSubscribersList. It will only send to the person you have sent to

Comment: thank u kid,but regarding email id where can i find it.

Comment: you can get this from the UI in content builder. Check the properties of the email you want to use for the send

Comment: hi kid,sorry for late response i need to send an email to a particular person where should i have to add that email id in my account,because i want to use that email id in  my code and i didn't find any email id in content builder can u please show case mean where can we add an email and find that id.